# Powershell copy files based on CSV contents

Tags: csv, powershell, copy

Morning Powershell users,
I'm trying to copy files listed in a .CSV document from one directory to another based on their file name. My .CSV document is just one column of filenames, it looks like this:

```
2.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
8.jpg
12.jpg
```

I have a folder of .jpgs from 1-900 in G:\Numbered\ and a destination folder for where the files should go at G:\Selections. This seems like it should be relatively simple but I think I'm missing something in my code. This is what I have so far:

```
import-CSV G:\fileList1.csv | foreach {copy-item G:\Numbered G:\Selections}
```

I looked around and I think I may need to use Get-Childitem but I'm not sure where. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your CSV look like this:

```
YourColumnName
2.jpg
4.jpg
n.jpg
```

Try this:

`Import-Csv fileList1.csv  | ForEach {Copy-Item "G:\Numbered\$($_.YourColumnName)" G:\Selections }`

But, if your CSV has only 1 column without a header, like this:

```
2.jpg
4.jpg
n.jpg
```

you should use `Get-Content` because it's not really a csv file. And your code should be:

```
Get-Content files.csv  | ForEach {Copy-Item G:\Numbered\$_ G:\Selections }
```

Comment: Using Get-Content worked perfectly! Thank you for the quick answer.